# How do I Insert Custom Cell into TableView Programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am trying to insert my custom cells into my table view with data that is loaded from a web request, but the table insert script is running before the data is loaded which has me ending up with a blank table.

Currently my code is this and I have tested it to work with dummy data:

```swift
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        mainTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
        mainTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        var cell : postWithTitleAndImageTableViewCell = mainTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postWithTitleAndImage") as postWithTitleAndImageTableViewCell
        let image = UIImage(named: "chainz on deck.jpg")
        var id = json[indexPath.row]["id"] as String
        var title = json[indexPath.row]["name"] as String
        var text = json[indexPath.row]["post"] as String
        var time = json[indexPath.row]["time"] as String
        var popularity = json[indexPath.row]["popularity"] as String
        //add clientid
        cell.setCell(id, title: title, image: image!, text: text, time: time, popularity: popularity)
        return cell as postWithTitleAndImageTableViewCell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)! Which the ID is: \(readIDs[indexPath.row])")
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return json.count
    }
```

The code does exactly what it's supposed to, except the `json` variable is loaded from a web request and the table is trying to insert before the data is actually loaded. How should I fix this? Is there a way to call for a manual insertion of a custom cell, or is there a way to call the `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` function once the data is loaded? What should I do?

Comment: You need to show your JSON loading code, but basically you need to call `tableView.reloadData()` once the JSON is loaded

Comment: @Paulw11 `mainTable.reloadData()` works but the data only shows up once the table is moved. If you don't try and scroll in the table it stays blank. Is there and way to fix this?

Comment: You need to show the code where you are loading the data and calling reload, but chances are you aren't dispatching reloadData on the main queue

Answer (score 0):

Using `mainTable.reloadData()` worked. Thanks @Paulw11